# How do you format from unix time stamp to local time in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How do you format from unix time stamp to local time in Django. The time template filter does not appear to work,

```
{{ unix_time_value|time:"TIME_FORMAT"}}
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should do that in the view with `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`. But I suppose you can defeat django's separation and write a template filter to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter that converts the unix timestamp to a datetime object:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='unix_to_datetime')
def unix_to_datetime(value):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(value))
```

and then you can use:

`{{ unix_time_value|unix_to_datetime|time:"TIME_FORMAT"}}`

More about custom template tags in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: builtins.NameError: name 'register' is not defined.  Documentation not saying what to import for register.

Comment: Edited my answer and added two lines I left out for brevity: `from django import template; register = template.Library()`

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp is most likely a float, in which case you'll need to convert it to a datetime object first.

Then optionally you can use Django's `timezone` to convert the datetime object to being timezone-aware based on current/default timezone... or simply use template filters

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestmp(my_unix_timestamp) # convert to datetime
# optionally
tz_dt = timezone.make_aware(dt, timezone.get_default_timezone())
```